# Where is my ViewPagerIndicator?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

Here is what my layout looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_below="@id/pager" 
        android:background="#808080"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my **onCreate()** based on the example snippet on the website:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new ScreenSlideAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        lineIndicator = (LinePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.titles);
        lineIndicator.setViewPager(pager);


    }
```

when I run the app, the indicator is not visible. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this mate:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:background="#808080"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/titles"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, it indeed did work. What did you change here ? Also, how can I make the indicator slightly larger ?

Answer (score 4):

The system reads elements from the top to the bottom of the XML file so your ViewPager is filling the entire height before the system knows that the ViewPagerIndicator needs to be under it. Swap the order and use `layout_above` instead:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:background="#808080"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/titles"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `03-03 11:44:12.119: E/AndroidRuntime(11417): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.viewpager_testproject/com.example.viewpager_testproject.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` :-(

Comment: You did make sure to swap the `android:id`s as well?

Comment: Like most weird XML problems, try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: Now my `ViewPager` disappeared xD what the heck ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/titles"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
    android:background="#808080" />

</RelativeLayout>
```